# The settlers 3, wine and DirectX

Tags: wine, games

I have here a Gold Edition of "The settlers 3" and I wanted to play with it on a Ubuntu machine, but somehow this does not work. I installed wine, installed "The settlers 3", but when I want to start is, I get this error:

```
"The Settlers III needs at least DirectX 3.0 to run."
```

But when I want to install `DX7A.EXE` from the CD, I am getting this error:

```
The package "Microsoft DirectX 7.0a-Setup" is not compatible with installed Version of Windows.
```

which is clear, because I have Ubuntu installed and not Windows.

So how to get this working.

Comment: There is information about this game in winehq (which should always be checked first for info about running games in wine) although it may be old.  https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31058

Answer (score 0):

First run this:

```
winetricks quartz
```

I assume you installed wine with `apt install wine` which comes with `winetricks`.

Then install the game normally.

I recommend for a flawlessly installation use CrossOver instead of plain Wine: https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/screenshot/settlers-3

Regards